# Flink CLI long response time

Tags: apache-flink

I am struggling with FLINK CLI, which became recently very slow in my dev environment built upon CentOS.
Flink version 1.10, but the same happens with 1.12. Also tried different versions of java (8,11).
Commands like start-cluster, flink list, flink run takes up to 2 minutes to finish.
Does anyone of you have any idea what might cause it? Is there any way to debug it?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that dns configuration was wrong in my machine. After setting it to working dns, everything started to work totally fine.